# GCC on OS X allocs more memory than expected

Tags: c, xcode, valgrind

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.4 with Xcode 7.3 with gcc compiler in it. I downloaded valgrind 3.11 using homebrew. When I run my C program with valgrind, this is the output

```
==4297== 
==4297== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4297==     in use at exit: 30,208 bytes in 188 blocks
==4297==   total heap usage: 265 allocs, 77 frees, 40,286 bytes allocated
==4297== 
==4297== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4297==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4297==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4297==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==4297==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==4297==         suppressed: 24,048 bytes in 186 blocks
==4297== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4297== 
==4297== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4297== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

In the whole program, I have 2 mallocs and 2 frees, so I have no idea why there are 265 allocs and fewer frees. I asked my friend who uses ubuntu for a help, and when he compiles my code with his gcc and run the program with valgrind, it brought back 3 allocs and 3 frees, so everything was correct. I found that this could happen in some compiler libraries, or if they are not up-to-date, but I have no idea how to update them in OS X.

- Here is my code

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "game.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    GAME team1;
    GAME team2;

    int len = 0; //only for valgrind

    if(argc == 2) {
        char* word;

        len = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;

        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
        strcpy(word, argv[1]);
        team1.team_name = word;

        len = strlen("Team 2") + 1;

        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
        strcpy(word, "Team 2");
        team2.team_name = word;

    } else if(argc == 3) {
        char* word;

        len = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;

        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
        strcpy(word, argv[1]);
        team1.team_name = word;

        len = strlen(argv[2]) + 1;

        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
        strcpy(word, argv[2]);
        team2.team_name = word;

    } else {
        char* word;

        len = strlen("Team 1") + 1;

        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
        strcpy(word, "Team 1");
        team1.team_name = word;

        len = strlen("Team 2") + 1;

        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
        strcpy(word, "Team 2");
        team2.team_name = word;
    }

    int player1, player2, players_number;

    do { //PVP or PVAI
        printf("How many players will play this game? [1/2]: ");
        scanf("%d", &players_number);
    } while((players_number != 1) && (players_number != 2));

    names(&team1, &team2); //add names
    abilities(&team1, &team2); //add hp, def, att

    render(&team1, &team2);

    //choosing first players
    printf("Choose player from Team 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &player1);

    while(getchar() != '\n')
        ;

    if(players_number == 2){
        printf("Choose player from Team 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &player2);

        while(getchar() != '\n')
            ;
    } else { //If PVAI
        srand(time(NULL));
        player2 = rand() % 5 + 1;
        printf("Choose player from Team 2: %d\n", player2);
    }
    /////////////////////////

    do { //GAME
        if(team1.hp[player1 - 1] == 0) {
            printf("Choose player from Team 1: ");
            scanf("%d", &player1);

                while(getchar() != '\n')
                    ;
        }

        if((team2.hp[player2 - 1] == 0) && (players_number == 2)) {
            printf("Choose player from Team 2: ");
            scanf("%d", &player2);

                while(getchar() != '\n')
                    ;
        } else if(team2.hp[player2 - 1] == 0) { //If PVAI

            do {
                player2 = rand() % 5 + 1;
            } while(team2.hp[player2 - 1] == 0);

            printf("Choose players from Team 2: %d\n", player2);
        }

        printf("---------------------------\n");

        battle(&team1, &team2, (player1 - 1), (player2 - 1));

        render(&team1, &team2);

    } while(who_wins(&team1, &team2) == 0);

        printf("Team %d wins!\n", who_wins(&team1, &team2));

    free(team1.team_name);
    free(team2.team_name);

    return 0;
}
```

game.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h> //for delay
#include <sys/stat.h> //for file size

#include "game.h"

void render(GAME *team1, GAME *team2) { //rendering the gaming table

    printf("%s\tHP\tDEF\tATT\n", team1->team_name);
    printf("---------------------------\n");

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", team1->name[i], team1->hp[i], team1->def[i], team1->att[i]);
    }

    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("%s\n", team2->team_name);
    printf("---------------------------\n");

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", team2->name[i], team2->hp[i], team2->def[i], team2->att[i]);
    }

    printf("---------------------------\n");

}

void names(GAME *team1, GAME *team2) { //choose random names from *.txt file
    printf("Generating teams...\n");
    FILE *fr = fopen("NAMES.txt", "r");
    if(fr == NULL) {
        printf("The file with names is not allowed, we will use pre-defined names for you.\n");
        non_generated_names(&team1, &team2);
        return; //can use exit instead of return and exit the program if names are not allowed
    }

    struct stat st;
    stat("NAMES.txt", &st);
    int size = st.st_size;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        fseek(fr, ((rand() % size) + 1), SEEK_SET);
        if(fscanf(fr, "%*s\n%20s", team1->name[i]) == EOF)
            i--;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        fseek(fr, ((rand() % size) + 1), SEEK_SET);
        if(fscanf(fr, "%*s\n%20s", team2->name[i]) == EOF)
            i--;
    }

    printf("Success!\n");
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    fclose(fr);
}

void non_generated_names(GAME **team1, GAME **team2) { //if *.txt file is not allowed, this is used for adding pre-defined names

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                strcpy((*team1)->name[i], "Jack");
                break;
            case 1:
                strcpy((*team1)->name[i], "Jim");
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy((*team1)->name[i], "John");
                break;
            case 3:
                strcpy((*team1)->name[i], "Tom");
                break;
            case 4:
                strcpy((*team1)->name[i], "Hank");
                break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                strcpy((*team2)->name[i], "Tim");
                break;
            case 1:
                strcpy((*team2)->name[i], "Mark");
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy((*team2)->name[i], "Alf");
                break;
            case 3:
                strcpy((*team2)->name[i], "Ted");
                break;
            case 4:
                strcpy((*team2)->name[i], "Bil");
                break;
        }
    }
}

void abilities(GAME *team1, GAME *team2) { //add HP, ATT and DEF to players

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

        team1->hp[i] = 5;
        team2->hp[i] = 5;

        team1->def[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
        team1->att[i] = 5 - team1->def[i];
        team2->def[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
        team2->att[i] = 5 - team2->def[i];

    }
}

int who_wins(GAME *team1, GAME *team2) { //tests if someone and who wins the game
    int win = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if(team1->hp[i] != 0) {
            win = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(win == 2)
        return 2;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if(team2->hp[i] != 0) {
            win = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(win == 1)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void change_attacker(int *attacker) { //swap 1 and 2

    if(*attacker == 1)
        *attacker = 2;
    else if(*attacker == 2)
        *attacker = 1;

}

void battle(GAME *team1, GAME *team2, int player1, int player2) { //Battle engine

    srand(time(NULL));
    int attacker = rand() % 2 + 1; //random team to start

    printf("Battle begins in few seconds...\n");
    //sleep(1); //disabled delays for testing
    if(attacker == 1) {
        printf("%s will starts...\n", team1->team_name);
    } else
        printf("%s will starts...\n", team2->team_name);

    //sleep(1);
    printf("\n!!!START!!!\n\n");
    printf("---------------------------\n");

    while((team1->hp[player1] != 0) && (team2->hp[player2] != 0)) {

        //sleep(1); //delay

        if(attacker == 1) {
            if((rand() % (team1->att[player1] + team2->def[player2]) + 1) > team2->def[player2]) {
                team2->hp[player2]--;
                printf("Attacker wins!\n");
                if(team2->hp[player2] != 0)
                    printf("%s from %s has been hit, %d HP remaining.\n", team2->name[player2],  team2->team_name, team2->hp[player2]);
                else
                    printf("%s from %s is dead!\n", team2->name[player2], team2->team_name);
                printf("---------------------------\n");
            } else {
                printf("Defender wins!\n");
                printf("---------------------------\n");
            }
        } else if(attacker == 2) {
            if((rand() % (team1->def[player1] + team2->att[player2]) + 1) > team1->def[player1]) {
                team1->hp[player1]--;
                printf("Attacker wins!\n");
                if(team1->hp[player1] != 0)
                    printf("%s from %s has been hit, %d HP remaining.\n", team1->name[player1], team1->team_name, team1->hp[player1]);
                else
                    printf("%s from %s is dead!\n", team1->name[player1], team1->team_name);
                printf("---------------------------\n");
            } else {
                printf("Defender wins!\n");
                printf("---------------------------\n");
            }
        }

        change_attacker(&attacker);
    }
}
```

Comment: without looking at the C code it's hard to answer your question

Comment: It might help to take the advice in the Valgrind output and *"Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory"*.

Comment: Aside: move `srand(time(NULL));` out of the not-always-executed `else` block (and out of all the other functions which have it) to the top of `main`.

Comment: for debugging, please post the contents of the `game.h` file

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc),  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any variable.  So do not clutter the code by casting the returned value.  3) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1, so is meaningless as a multiplier in a parameter.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the desired command line parameter was actually entered.    When not enough command line parameters are entered, output a `usage` message to stderr and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code block beginning with: `while(getchar() != '\n')` should always check (first) for EOF.  I.E. `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: the calls to `scanf()` are allowing the user to enter a negative value!  Then many of the following statements in the code will result in eratic behaviour of the code.   Suggest:  `player = -1; while(  0>player || MAX_PLAYER_NUM < player) { if( 1 != scanf( "%u", player ) ) { // handle error and exit }  }`

Comment: strongly suggest: revise the code so the numerous checks of a player number being 0 or 1 or 2 via 'if' statements be modified to use `switch(player) { case 0: ... break;  case 1: ... break; case 2: ... break; default: ... break; }`

Comment: I observe that we can't compile your code (no `game.h`), which means it is fiddly working out what's going wrong, if anything, with your memory management.  Please strive to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) so we can see what is happening.

Comment: due to the precedence of operators in C, this kind of line: `team1->def[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;` will result in a value in the range `0...4`  But the code seems to expect `1...4`  Suggest using: `team1->def[i] = (rand() % 4) + 1;`

Comment: using the function: `sleep()` has some problems suggest using `nanosleep()` instead

Comment: as stated in a prior comment, this expression: `(rand() % (team1->def[player1] + team2->att[player2]) + 1)` will not work as expected.  Suggest adding appropriate parens so execution order is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you're seeing is 'normal' on Mac OS X.  The C startup code does a lot of memory allocation before calling `main()`, and most of it is not freed.  The suppressions are important.

Creating a program like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and running it on my Mac OS X 10.11.4 machine (GCC 6.1.0) yields:

```
==58367== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==58367== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==58367== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==58367== Command: ./xx
==58367== 
==58367== 
==58367== HEAP SUMMARY:
==58367==     in use at exit: 22,233 bytes in 186 blocks
==58367==   total heap usage: 270 allocs, 84 frees, 28,465 bytes allocated
==58367== 
==58367== LEAK SUMMARY:
==58367==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58367==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58367==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58367==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58367==         suppressed: 22,233 bytes in 186 blocks
==58367== 
==58367== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==58367== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I get similar results compiling with `clang` from XCode.  The `-v` option is noisy but informative.

All that memory allocation is routine, and not something it is worth worrying about.

In your output from `valgrind`, you have some possibly lost and some still reachable memory.  You should explore further to find out what those are.  The `--leak-check=full` option will help.  You may end up using `--gen-suppressions` option too (`valgrind --help` to explore the options available), and then `--suppressions=your-suppressions-file` when rerunning.

I have a file with 22 suppressions in it that I sometimes need to use.  I used to have a lot more suppressions, but `valgrind` has got better at doing them automatically.  Keeping `valgrind` current is generally a good idea too; rebuilding after a Mac OS X upgrade is a good idea.

---

> How I can check my program if OS X allocs memory by itself?

#### `leak13.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(33);
    strcpy(s, "Adjudication");
    printf("[%s]\n", s);
    /* free(s); // leak! */
    return 0;
}
```

#### Running with valgrind

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full leak13
==2301== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2301== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2301== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2301== Command: leak13
==2301== 
[Adjudication]
==2301== 
==2301== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2301==     in use at exit: 26,362 bytes in 188 blocks
==2301==   total heap usage: 272 allocs, 84 frees, 32,594 bytes allocated
==2301== 
==2301== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 65
==2301==    at 0x100007CF1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==2301==    by 0x100000F4D: main (leak13.c:7)
==2301== 
==2301== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2301==    definitely lost: 33 bytes in 1 blocks
==2301==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2301==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2301==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2301==         suppressed: 26,329 bytes in 187 blocks
==2301== 
==2301== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2301== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 18)
$
```

Here, there's clearly one leak, from the `malloc()` at line 7 in the source code.  (And this was run on Mac OS X 10.11.5 without having rebuilt `valgrind` or `gcc` since the upgrade.  It doesn't seem to have mattered this time around.)

When you run a program on Linux, you can get a completely clean bill of health.
For example, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with the code as above except the `free` is uncommented out, I got the output:

```
$ valgrind ./noleak13
==38142== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==38142== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==38142== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==38142== Command: ./noleak13
==38142== 
[Adjudication]
==38142== 
==38142== HEAP SUMMARY:
==38142==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38142==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 33 bytes allocated
==38142== 
==38142== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==38142== 
==38142== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==38142== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

You won't see the 'All heap blocks were free — no leaks are possible' message on Mac OS X, but you can 0 bytes lost, 0 bytes indirectly lost, 0 bytes possibly lost and 0 bytes still reachable — apart from the suppressed items — which is as good as it gets.

Comment: And if i can ask, how is possible that my friend who uses ubuntu does have 3 allocs and 3 frees in this same file? I understand that we have different operation systems, but we are both only a students, and we have to do our programs with similar number of allocs and frees because it is controled, so how I can check my program if OS X allocs memory by itself?

Comment: And is this "still reachable" and "possibly lost" blocks problems? Because i don't know why they are there and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Still reachable means that there is a chain of pointers to the memory, so it isn't leaked but it is still allocated.  You have to evaluate the information that `valgrind` gives, often rerunning the program with extra options to find more information.  If the trace for a memory block doesn't reach your `main()`, then the chances are the memory block is managed by the system and there's nothing you can do about it.  Just make sure the call chain is long enough (`--num-callers=32` instead of the default 12, for example).

Comment: One of the suppressions I have is `{ Mac-OS-X-10.11.4-Leak-001 Memcheck:Leak match-leak-kinds: reachable fun:malloc_zone_malloc fun:_read_images fun:object_setClass fun:gc_init fun:preopt_init fun:map_images_nolock fun:_ZL25batchFinalizeOnTwoThreadsP14_malloc_zone_tPFvP16auto_zone_cursorPFvPvS3_ES3_ES2_m fun:_ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE fun:_ZN4dyld36registerImageStateBatchChangeHandlerE17dyld_image_statesPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE fun:dyld_register_image_state_change_handler fun:_objc_init fun:_os_object_init }` (spread over many lines).

Comment: No mention of `main` — there isn't anything I can do about it, which is why it is suppressed.