# memory leakage when printing floating point value

Tags: c++, macos, memory-leaks, valgrind

In my MacOS(El Capitan 10.11.5) I wrote very simple code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n" << 4.f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I built and tested memory leakage:

```
g++ ./test.cpp
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

The result shows that there are memory leakage!

```
==46149== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==46149== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==46149== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==46149== Command: ./a.out
==46149==
--46149-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./a.out" warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
test4
==46149==
==46149== HEAP SUMMARY:
==46149==     in use at exit: 26,357 bytes in 194 blocks
==46149==   total heap usage: 260 allocs, 66 frees, 32,133 bytes allocated
==46149==
==46149== 148 (80 direct, 68 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 44 of 67
==46149==    at 0x100009EBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==46149==    by 0x1002AC8D6: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002AD21F: __d2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002A9877: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002D23E6: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002FB6C8: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002DF914: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002DF973: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1002CFE1D: snprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x10003C752: std::__1::num_put<char, std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, std::__1::ios_base&, char, double) const (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1000229AD: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(float) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x100000FF7: main (in ./a.out)
==46149==
==46149== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 61 of 67
==46149==    at 0x10000A17C: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==46149==    by 0x1005E2EFD: _objc_copyClassNamesForImage (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D6182: protocols() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D6093: readClass(objc_class*, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D3C13: gc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005DB24E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005E8132: layout_string_create (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D683C: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D6300: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D62E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D62E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==    by 0x1005D62E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==46149==
==46149== LEAK SUMMARY:
==46149==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==46149==    indirectly lost: 68 bytes in 2 blocks
==46149==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==46149==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==46149==         suppressed: 20,049 bytes in 189 blocks
==46149== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==46149== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==46149==
==46149== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==46149== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 18)
```

If I change the floating point value (4.f) to an integer value(4) there's no definitely lost leaks. I also tested in the linux machine and there's no problem.

Since this is very simple code, it seems like there's some problem in my Mac. Is there anyone who knows this problem?

## added Mac OS Instruments results

As shown in the following screenshots, printing floating value makes memory leakage.

[image: Printing floating point makes memory leakage!]

[image: Printing integer does not make memory leakage.]

Comment: The runtime library maybe does some initial allocation that it needs for the duration of the program? And since such memory if released by the operating system when the program exits it simply doesn't care releasing it explicitly?

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you want to debug your program, using a debugger or tools such as Valgrind, you should make it a habit to build with the `-g` flag to add debug information.

Comment: Does the memory leak grow if you repeat some parts of the code? If not, it's not a memory leak.

Comment: [This post may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242021/gcc-on-os-x-allocs-more-memory-than-expected)

Comment: At least glibc uses malloc during printf for float numbers.

Comment: If profiling using the Instruments, it does not report something related to system(like copySwiftV1MangledName') but it still reports the definitely lost memories.